# BeautifulSoup modify an anchor tag in place?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to grab all anchor tags within an html document. These anchor tags can live anywhere at any depth. Once I have the links, I process them and then I generate a new link.

I want to modify the original HTML to contain these new links in the anchor tags.

Here is what I have so far:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(...)
links = soup.findAll("a")

for link in links:
    new_link = process_href(a['href'])
    # Now I want to replace this anchor tag href with new_link

# Should print out entire html with the new links
print soup.prettify()
```

How can this be accomplished? Since each anchor tag is at a specific location in the HTML, is it possible to modify the tag in place with BeautifulSoup? Or would a string-based solution work better (ie, convert entire HTML to String and do some sort of string replace)? The problem with the latter is that I still need a way to individually process the href links to generate the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just modify soup elements:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/'))
first_link = soup('a')[0]
print first_link
# <a href="//stackoverflow.com">current community</a>
first_link['href'] = first_link['href'].replace('//', 'http://')
print first_link
# <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">current community</a>
```